# kCFNumberFormatter round differences

Tags: objective-c, number-formatting, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I found an interesting question what's not described on the internet, even is misleading in the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberFormatterRef/Reference/reference.html). What are the differences between:

```
kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling

kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor

kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown

kCFNumberFormatterRoundUp

kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven

kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfDown

kCFNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp
```

?

kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling explanation is equal with kCFNumberFormatterRoundUp but they are not working the same, the same case in kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor and kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown

Comment: What exactly is misleading in the documentation?

Comment: kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling explanation is equal with kCFNumberFormatterRoundUp but they are not working the same, the same case in kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor and kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown

Comment: Perhaps you should add that to the question to make clear what you are asking. (Seems a good question to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is indeed ambigous. Both `kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor` and 
`kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown` are documented as

> Round down to next larger number with the proper number of fraction
>   digits.

A small test shows that these rounding modes give different results for *negative numbers*.

`kCFNumberFormatterRoundFloor` behaves similar to the `floor()` function.
It rounds always to a smaller (or equal) value.
On the other hand `kCFNumberFormatterRoundDown` rounds "towards zero", i.e. it returns
gives a number whose absolute value is smaller or equal to the absolute value of the input.

*Example: (using `NSNumberFormatter`)*

```
NSNumberFormatter *f1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f1 setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[f1 setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];

NSNumberFormatter *f2 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f2 setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
[f2 setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

double x = -1.5;
NSLog(@"%@, %@", [f1 stringFromNumber:@(x)], [f2 stringFromNumber:@(x)]);
// Output: -2, -1

x = + 3.5;
NSLog(@"%@, %@", [f1 stringFromNumber:@(x)], [f2 stringFromNumber:@(x)]);
// Output: 3, 3
```

Similarly, `kCFNumberFormatterRoundCeiling` returns a value that is larger or equal
to the input (like `ceil()`), and `kCFNumberFormatterRoundUp` rounds "away from zero".